# Why this lambda expression got wrong

Tags: java

What is wrong with the following code? `list.removeIf(p -> p.contains("hello"));`

```
import java.util.*;
public class NewClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello", " hello world", " hello china", "chi", "hi");
        System.out.println(list);

        list.removeIf(p -> p.contains("hello"));
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "got wrong" about this code?  Please be specific about what is wrong, including any compiler error, exception with stack trace, or incorrect output.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow James. I hope you get the help you need on this site. To maximize the benefit you get out of the site, I would recommend reading the following doc on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arrays.asList()` returns a fixed-size list. See the javadoc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

So you cannot add or remove items from the returned List object.

Instead you can create your own instance of a list:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("hello", " hello world", " hello china", "chi", "hi"));
```

You still get the benefit of using `asList()` to create the list conveniently, but by constructing a **new** instance of `ArrayList` it is fully modifiable.

Comment: No need to write *"Pretty sure"* here, since you're very right. And your fix is also correct. Can you please explain why it works, so OP can understand it?

Comment: @James_shnu Feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your question.

Comment: Your list is not implemented by java.util.ArrayList, but java.util.Arrays$ArrayList instead. This implementation apply some restrictions on list returned by Arrays#asList as you see in documentation